# simple graphic pipeline in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, pipeline

I am reading Schaum's outlines COMPUTER GRAPHICS. Book says that a simple graphic pipeline is something like this: **geometric representation --> transformation --> scan conversion**
(though the author has decided to teach scan conversion chapter before transformation chapter). I wish to learn this simple pipeline through an example in openGL. suppose I wish to create a line with end coordinates (150,400) and (700,100) in window of size (750,500). Below code works very well. All I am asking to experts is to explain the 'steps in sequence' when is transformation happening and when scan conversion. I know it may sound stupid but I really need to get this straight. I am just an adult beginner learning graphics at my own as a hobby.
My guess is that scan conversion is not happening here in program. it is done by openGL automatically between glBegin and glEnd calls. **Am I right?**

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void init(void)
{
        glClearColor (0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.0);
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);      
        glColor4f(0.5,0.7,0.3,0.0);
        glLineWidth(3);
}

void display(void)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2i(50, 400);
    glVertex2i(700, 100);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, (GLdouble)w, 0.0, (GLdouble)h);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,150);
    glutInitWindowSize(750,500); // aspect ratio of 3/2
    glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();         // this is when the frame buffer is displayed on the screen
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: What is the year that book was written?

Comment: @KromStern in year 1986. the code is NOT from the book

Comment: You better get something more up to date. I mean basics remained the same, but the vocabulary changed since then. I assume now it's Virtual Geometry -> Projection -> Rasterization

Comment: I agree with Krom here. The definition of "graphic pipeline" has changed a lot during the last 28 years.

Answer (score 1):

All stages done within OpenGL implementation (mostly in hardware). You specify states and data, then GL will - if speaking in terms of old GL 1.0 - assemble data into vertices, pass every vertex through transformation stage, rasterize resulting primitives into fragments, perform per-fragment tests (that may discard some fragments), and update resulting pixels on render target.

There is no point in user code that may be on 'one stage' in pipeline - it doesn't have callbacks, and usually as many as possible stages working at the same time.